# Open URL Scheme through Widget Tap (iOS 16 Widget Kit)

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit, ios16

Here is the code I currently have however, it does not seem to be working. This example says I want to open the calc app. My goal is to open an app once a widget is clicked.

@main App Code:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .onOpenURL { url in
                print("Received deep link: \(url)")
            }
    }
}
```

Widget Code:

```
Gauge(value: 50), in: 0.0...100.0) {
            } currentValueLabel: {
                Text(Open App)
            }
            .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
            .widgetURL(URL(string: "calc://")!)
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie

Comment: Are you trying to open your app or a different app? Widgets can't directly open another app. If you want to open your app, did you register the custom URL?

Comment: @Yrb I am trying to open a different app.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to do this in a 2 step process. First, you need to set up your app to receive custom URLs from your widget. This is shockingly well explained by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app). Once you have your app's custom url scheme set up, it is time to set up your widget. Essentially what you are going to do is send a URL with a query that is the URL you want to open. Back in your app, you receive that URL, parse it out, and then call `openUrl()` with the URL you want to open, and that app will open.

Your code above is close. Following Apple's example above, try this:

In your widget create a deep link URL:

```
func createDeeplinkForCalc() -> URL {
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "myphotoapp"
    components.host = "com.example.myphotoapp"
    components.path = "/calc"
    components.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "open", value: "calc://")
    ]
    
    return components.url!
}
```

Then, in `.widgetURL`, pass this:
.widgetURL(createDeeplinkForCalc())

In your main app:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .onOpenURL { url in
                handleURL(url: URL)
            }
    }
}

func handleURL(_ url:URL) {
    // This makes sure you got the correct URL
     guard url.scheme == "myphotoapp",
         url.host == "com.example.myphotoapp"
     else { return }
        
     let query = parseQuery(url: url)

     guard let urlString = query["open"],
           !urlString.isEmpty else { return } // make sure something exists in the value

     if let calcURL = URL(string: urlString) {
         openURL(calcURL) // this calls "calc://" and opens the calculator
    }

    private func parseQuery(url: URL) -> Query {
         guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
               let queryItems = components.queryItems
         else { return ["":""] }
        
          return queryItems.reduce(into: Query()) { (result, item) in
            result[item.name] = item.value
        }
    }
}
```

The above has not been tested, but should work.

Comment: A good example of using reduce method! :)

Comment: Thank you. OP seems to have abandoned the question.